# Track MSSQL 2008 table changes, what is the best method?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, monitoring

I need to track records changes in one MSSQL table from .NET 4.0 application. What is the best method to do that?

More description about the app. We have membership table which is updated from application #1. We also developing application #2, which should track membership table and send e-mail notification on certain membership data changes.

Comment: so everyone else reading knows, what version of Sql-server?

Comment: You need to know any change in general or what change exactly made? I guess the key is to select the shema database, select user tables, columns, etc. Then calc a checksum or store it into another user defined table. You can comppare current state from shema and your store then and seek the differences.

Comment: @YvesR only get event when changes appears.

Comment: I thought you want to track if the application change the DB structure, like add tables, add columns, drop, etc. By this event you have to do it like I mentioned before. If you only want to track the data inside the tables, then simple store the last record_id with a timestamp or USN number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a history table (A table with the same columns as the original table, plus an auto-increment ID column), you can track everything about changes to the original table. You can track inserts, deletes, and every change.  Use triggers for insert, update, and deletes to put a row into the history table. If you don't need all these options, then use those that you do need.

If you choose to use an IsDeleted flag in the original table, it complicates every query, and leaves your active table with lots of unneeded rows. But that can work, depending on your needs.

check out this link.. for more information....
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DTS_SQLExpress.aspx

Answer (score 7):

*For DML changes:*
In SQL Server 2008, you have a built-in feature for this purpose: [Change data capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

*For DDL changes:* Starting with SQL Server 2005 you have [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989.aspx), [Example](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL-Server/DDL-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-34.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i think you need to do.

Create a trigger on SQL tables which will create a file in one folder everytime the data is updated.

Create [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)  in Application 1 and 2 which will monitor that folder.

In the callback function of FileWatcher, write code to send email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Open-Source class [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener). It is pretty easy to configure and use:

```
// See constructor optional parameters to configure it according to your needs
var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(connectionString, "YourDatabase", "YourTable");

// e.Data contains actual changed data in the XML format
listener.TableChanged += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Your table was changed!");

// After you call the Start method you will receive table notifications with 
// the actual changed data in the XML format
listener.Start();

// ... Your code is here 

// Don't forget to stop the listener somewhere!
listener.Stop();
```

Hope this helps.